# How to include percentage in excel cells

Tags: excel, formula

I have this formula that I am able to convert to percentage as in 1).

1) ROUNDDOWN(AP1/1000,1)

However, if I add text infront of the the formula as in 2) the number is not able to convert to percentage. Can anyone help.

2) "text" & ROUNDDOWN(AP1/1000,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `TEXT` function. `=TEXT(ROUNDDOWN(AP1/1000,1);"0,0%")`.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx